# Why do we have to have late return type?

Tags: c++, decltype

Take a look at this:

```
template<class T>
struct X
{
private:
    T value_;
public:
    X():value_(T()) {}
    X(T value):value_(value) {}

    T getValue() const
    {
        return value_;
    }

    static const T value = 0; //this is dummy

    template<class D, class U>
    friend decltype(X<D>::value + X<U>::value) operator + (X<D> lhs, X<U> rhs);
};

template<class T, class U>
decltype(X<T>::value + X<U>::value) operator + (X<T> lhs, X<U> rhs)
{
    return lhs.getValue() + rhs.getValue();
    /* THIS COMPILES WITH VS2010 but line below doesn't which is incorrect
     * behaviour in my opinion because: friendship has been declared and
     * access to private data should be granted.*/
    return lhs.value_ + rhs.value_; //THIS COMPILES WITH GCC 4.6
}
```

And after example like this there must come the question (by the way the whole example compiles and works as intended), anyway here is the question:

Do we really have to have the pug ugly syntax with late return type? As I proved in this example it can be done "the normal way".

**Edited** (now without this dreaded static dummy - all singing all dancing)

```
template<class T>
struct X
{
private:
    T value_;
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    X():value_(T()) {}
    X(T value):value_(value) {}
    T getValue()const { return value_; }

    template<class D, class U>
    friend X<decltype(typename X<D>::value_type() + typename X<U>::value_type())> operator + (X<D> lhs, X<U> rhs);
};

template<class T, class U>
X<decltype(typename X<T>::value_type() + typename X<U>::value_type())> operator + (X<T> lhs, X<U> rhs)
{
    return lhs.getValue() + rhs.getValue();
    //return lhs.value_ + rhs.value_; //VS is __wrong__ not allowing this code to compile
}
```

Comment: What's the compilation error on VS2010?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it just doesn't work without trailing return type, because the compiler has no way of knowing what the programmer asks it to do or what the involved types are.

Take this simple forwarding-wrapper template function (that's not a made up example, but taken from some real code I wrote not long ago):

```
template<typename T, typename... A> auto fwd(T fp, A...a) -> decltype(fp(a...))
{
    // some other code
    return fp(a...);
};
```

This function can be called with any kind of unknown function pointer that has any kind of unknown return type. It will work, it will return the correct type, and it doesn't confuse the compiler.

Without the trailing return type, the compiler would have no way of figuring out what's going on.

You could get a similar effect with a `#define` and abusing the comma operator, but eugh... at what price.

Comment: But why did the language architects not choose `decltype(fp(a...)) fwd(T fp, A...a)` instead. It's just syntax. I guess there's a syntactic issue?

Comment: That's something I can't answer, only someone in the committee would know. My guess is that it would require two passes over the source, one pass only to gather the type information, and the second one with `decltype` filled in (and possibly recursion, ouch). The way the parser gets to see the source, this won't work in one pass, because at the time `decltype()` is seen, it has no clue what the stuff in parenthese refers to (even if it becomes clear later in the same line). They probably didn't want to make parsing that convoluted.

Answer (score 3):

All this is missing the better readability it adds, without needing to use typedefs or alias templates

```
auto f() -> void(*)();
```

Compare that to the equivalent

```
void (*f())();
```

You can also access `this` in a late specified return type, but not in the early return type

```
class A {
  std::vector<int> a;
public:
  auto getVector() -> decltype((a));
  auto getVector() const -> decltype((a));
};
```

If you had it the other way around, it wouldn't work, because `this` would not be in scope, and `decltype((a))` would have the same type both time (no implicit `this` would be added, so the type of `this` could not influence the type of `(a)`).

Comment: @Johann thanks for your answer, one issue though it doesn't compile with VS2010 sp1 (but that's their problem not yours). Using gcc 4.6 I was able to compile following fnc of A class: decltype((a)) get_vector(); Would you mind and explain to me why this is worst to your version with trailing return type? Undoubtedly my version is more readable, would you agree with me on that?

Comment: @There, it will give `decltype((a))` always the type `std::vector<int>&`, no matter whether or not you put that for a const or non-const member function. If you put it in a late specified return type, then it will be `std::vector<int> const&` when the member function is `const`. Also, calling functions isn't possible at all if you put the `decltype(...)` at the early return type (unless you use those ugly workarounds you presented or using `declval` etc). For calling member functions of `A`, you have to put it at the end, so `this` is in scope.

Comment: @There - VS2010 has the problem that the rules were changed after it was released. I belive the decision to allow decltype((a)) here (a meaning this->a) was made in 2011.

Comment: @Johann which ugly workaround you reffer to? And this whole business with decltype etc came from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/59eb933e-a72b-4764-93de-a253d27184c7 where I've tried unsuccessfully declare friend ;)

Comment: @There I think you know what I mean. For example, to make @Damon's code work with early return type, you would have to do `declval<T>()(declval<A>()...)`. And then you will some time notice in a few corner cases it's still not equivalent, and start writing `declval<T>()(declval<typename std::remove_extent<A>::type*>()...)`, and then notice how ugly it became, compared to simply writing `decltype(fp(a...))`.

Comment: @Johann No I don't know what you mean so would you mind tell me?, second point is that there isn't just one right way of doing things, and that sometimes it is better to use decltype as an early return type instead of late, and third point is that it is impossible (AFAIC) to declare in natural way a friendship to a fnc with trailing-return-type if the function is using private members of class declaring this friendship which is contradictory to the friend meaning. So would you mind (if you can) solve the puzzle with operator+? And woudl you mind tell me which ugly workaround I'm using?

Comment: and Johann if you say that my solution uses some ugly workarounds (although I've never stated that they're beatuiful they are just workarounds for current constraints) how would you call James's Kranze solution? Would you preffer to see that? I think you don't. Anyway as for the time being there is no way (with condition that fnc has to use private members of X and there is no getter in X) of declaring  friendship between X and auto fnc(X var)->decltype(var.priv_mem), my approach seems to be most natural and obvious, and most of all correct and typesafe.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without `decltype`, but this has some drawbacks. You either need an additional template parameter or you need to rely on the convention that adding two items of type `T` produces an item of type `T`.

Comment: but the only point I'm trying to make here is that auto is unnecessary and we can have normal return type position. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, by "late return type", you mean
what C++11 calls the trailing return type.  In the case you
present, there's no problem, and if you don't want to use the
trailing return type, there's no reason to do so.  If the return
type depends on the argument types, however, it can be extremely
verbose to have to repeat them in the `decltype`:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add( T1 lhs, T2 rhs ) -> decltype( lhs + rhs );
```

To avoid using the trailing return type, you'd have to write
something like:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
decltype( (*(T1*)0 + *(T2*)0 ) add( T1 lhs, T2 rhs );
```

It's a lot clearer what the return type is in the first example,
and if the parameter types are more complicated (e.g. something
like `std::vector<T1>`), it's also a lot more succinct:

```
template <typename T>
auto findInVector( std::vector<T> const& v ) -> decltype( v.begin() );
```

vs.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator
        findInVector( std::vector<T> const& v );
```

Comment: @James as I've shown in my example I don't have to write pug ugly syntax in form (*(T1*)0 + *(T2*)0).

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: What you have shown in the example is that you can change the syntax that @James has used if you add a dummy static member to the class, which in my opinion is much worse than @James approach, since you are changing the class design to provide for a particular usage in a function. I.e. the class itself is not driven by the design of what it is modelling, but rather by the awkward need of avoiding the `*(T*)0` syntax.

Comment: @David you are the only (except James) person who thinks that this: (*(T1*)0 + *(T2*)0 is better to this: (X<T>::value + X<U>::value). Get serious and if you don't believe me ask around.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: No, the problem is not with `X<T>::value` but with the comment in the definition of that static member: `//this is dummy`, which means that you have changed the class to add something spurious and unneeded in the design just to demonstrate that you can get away without the conversions. You are only looking at the low level C++ quirks and forgetting that when you program you are not exercising the language, but rather *solving* a problem, and if in the domain of the problem `X` does not need a `value` static member, adding it to avoid `*(T*)0` is wrong.

Comment: @David in std:: templates I've seen hundreds _dummy's. So it is a practice other used too in order to solve some problem.

Comment: @David and if now your saying No to my question and in your previous comment you've said something completely opposite what does it mean?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: The expression wasn't `((T1)0 +(T2)0)`, but `(*(T1*)0 + *(T2*)0)`.  And my example is taken directly from an example in the standard, so clearly, the majority of the committee members thought it was more likely to be used that introducing unnecessary static variables (which is so horrible that most committee members didn't even think anyone could consider it).

Comment: @James Bjarne says about similiar example (somewhere in The C++ Programming Langauge): Horrible, so I stick with his opinion, and how can you be sure that commitee members didn't even think anyone could consider it? Did you ask anyone of them? And as for readability - well, answer for yourself.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Can you specify where Bjarne makes this comment.  The latest versions of The C++ Programming Language that I've seen date to well before the introduction of trailing return types, so I don't think he comments on them there.  As for what the committee members think, I'm judging from discussions in the committee mailing lists.  (I'm a technical expert for AFNOR, although I've not been active lately.)

Comment: @James Bjarne doesn't talk about trailing-return-type he just gives very similiar example, but you know what, I'll find this example for you (not today though, some day next week) and then you can judge for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this question, are you asking why the language allows you to do:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto foo( X<T> lhs, X<U> rhs ) -> decltype( lhs + rhs );
```

Instead of *forcing* you to *artificially* add a static dummy member to the `X` template so that you can type:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
decltype( X<T>::unneeded_artificial_static_member +
          X<U>::unneeded_artificial_static_member )
foo( X<T> lhs, X<U> rhs ) -> decltype( lhs + rhs );
```

Seriously? I mean, you can use other less burdensome constructs if you want, like:

```
template <typename T>
T& lvalue_of();

template <typename T, typename U>
decltype( lvalue_of< X<T> > + lvalue_of< X<U> > )
foo( X<T> lhs, X<U> rhs );
```

And then be forced to use specific variants of the `lvalue_of` when needed:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
decltype( lvalue_of< X<T> > + lvalue_of< X<U> const > )
foo( X<T> lhs, X<U> const & rhs );
```

And then create extra variants for `rvalue_ref`... for each potential use case that you might come around, but why on earth would you prefer the standard to force you to those weird error prone (will you remember to update the `decltype` if you change the argument?) constructs to define the type, when *after* the argument declaration the compiler can so easily do it itself in a safe simple safe way?

With that line of reasoning, you should also drop lambdas from the language altogether, they are not an enabling feature at all. The enabling feature was being able to use a local class in a template:

```
std::function< void () > f = [](){ std::cout << "Hi"; };
```

can be easily implemented as:

```
struct lambda {
   void operator()() {
      std::cout << "Hi";
   }
};
std::function< void () > f = lambda();
```

And then you can probably think of a good amount of other features that can be as easily dropped from the language, since there are workarounds.

Comment: @David yes I do see that you don't get this question. Let me slowly explain once again: The only thing I'm questioning here (and forget my artificial demo example) is that we don't really need auto keyword (I've proved this, you've proved this) and if commitee would worked bit better we could have avoid **completely** trailing-return-type. That's all what I'm saying here.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I can prove that you don't need `const` or `mutable`, or lambdas in the language, among other features. The question is not whether it is strictly necessary (heck, there are no features in C++0x that we have not been coding without in the last few years, so they are not needed!), the actual question is whether the features make the development better, safer, faster or easier. It is not that I did not understand your question, but rather that you failed to understand my answer, not having the trailing return type would make code more awkward and error prone.

Comment: Would you really prefer not to have that feature? Don't use it, it is as simple as that. But for me, and the committee, it seems like a nice little thing to have. In the same way that it is nice to have type deduction in function template arguments instead of forcing you to provide the type (another feature that was discussed when added to the language, and some felt it was not needed), it is nice that the compiler can do it's magic and help me in solving my real problem.

Comment: @David so you are telling me that you wouldn't like to have template<class T, class U> decltype(value + value_1 ) f(T value, U value_1 ){...} and instead of this you preffer to have trailing return type? Why?

Comment: @David and David I don't talk about workarounds I'm talking about easier way to do things with the same level of protection.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: the change a couple of lines above would break the top-down approach and scopes of current C++. The return type is not in the scope of the function, and the compiler would have to look forward into the signature. It would also potentially break existing code: `int x; decltype( x ) foo( double x );` what `x` is to be used in the `decltype`? will it return `int` or `double`? If X contains an internal type `type` what is the meaning of: `typedef int type; type X::foo() { return type(); }`? In C++03: it means `int X::foo() { return X::type(); }`

Comment: @David To your first Q, double (by scope resolution), and in the second example you're asking about what exactly? And above all one should avoid identical identifiers.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: the `auto` keyword was added for other reasons; it definitely makes code clearer, more concise, and easier to maintain, e.g. when used instead of `std::vector<MyType>::const_iterator` in a `for` loop.  And having to introduce additional, unused static variables is a cure far, far worse than the disease (assuming that the trailing return types are a disease---I rather like them).

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be `lvalue_of< X<T> >()` (instead of your `lvalue_of< X<T> >`)?

Comment: @James David Rodriguez would argue with you on the subject "what for was the auto introduced", wouldn't you David, or have you checked this and now you agree with James (and me) the main reason for which was auto introduced? @James, pity I don't have really time to find this thread but believe me David's opinion on auto and the **main** reason behind (according to him) it would really surprise you, am I right David?

Comment: @sbi: Right, I missed the required () on the code snippet. @There is nothing: the second question is exactly as it reads: *what should the code above mean?* and I already provided the current interpretation. Now if you are to extend the scope of the function (where the arguments are defined) back to the start of the function signature (i.e. to include the return type) so that you can do `template <typename T> decltype( a+b ) sum( T a, T b );` (that requires `a` and `b` to be accessible at the return position) then you would change the semantics of that particular example.

Comment: @There is...: By your answer to Q1, I take that you are fine with changing the semantics and potentially breaking correct code, as that is what you would do if you extend the scope of the function to include the return type. On the other hand, the committee --that includes some very smart, smarter than you and me, and experienced people, again more experienced than both of us-- thought otherwise.

Comment: Why do you think that I would argue with @James on the reasons for the introduction of `auto`, I don't recall ever having said anything against, have I? where? The other thing is that I am not sure of what thread you might be referring to, but I do agree with @James, `auto` was created to delegate the responsibility of selecting the type to the compiler and simplify code. Now, `auto` in the context of a return type (as compared to a local variable) was added to allow you to use the `decltype` as a trailing return type (i.e. to use `decltype` on the arguments of the function).

Comment: @David check my edited version, second you're asking about thread? That was the thread when you and sbi (but in fairness he wasn't commited to it, but you were), so that the thread I'm talking about in which you were saying that the main reason for introducing auto was to allow unnamed expressions to be "typed" - by using auto and on the right hand side lambda expression and I was saying exactly what James, now you remember? But if you not and if this topic hasn't been deleted (for there was lot's of comments) I'll find it for you and you'll be able to read what you're saying back then.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: `auto` was added long before trailing return types were even suggested, so it obviously wasn't added to support them.

Comment: @David Rodriguez Now I think I understand: `auto` was extended so that it could be used as the return type of a function in order to allow trailing return types.

Comment: @There is nothing: Right I forgot that particular case. As before `auto` is a nice to have feature for compactness of code, and an *enabling* feature to capture results of expressions of unknown type. I stand by my previous words, which I had forgotten (thanks for the reminder :) since I have not been reading anything on `auto` for a while, and I am stucked with g++4.0 at work, so I have not been playing with it either. The most important use case of `auto` is *enabling* storage of expressions of unknown types (as lambdas)

Comment: @David by your last sentence you're wrong (according to Bjarne's opinion on the auto subject).

Comment: @There is nothing: On the edit change of the static member for a internal type and using `decltype( typename X<T>::value_type() )`, looks much better than before, but it is not idiot-proof. It will only work for instantiations of the template with type arguments that can be value-initialized. I.e. it will fail for types that might be addable but not default constructible. It is much better than the original version.

Comment: @There is nothing: Can you provide a link to an article where Bjarne defends a different position?

Comment: @David: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#auto read and cry ;), and if you don't have enough you can also check n1984. And David - don't change your wording, in the thread where we had discussion on auto **you were saying** that: **main** reason for introducing auto was enabling lambdas to be store in a variable, now what your saying has different meaning and is arguable.

Comment: @There is nothing: :) I don't think I will cry over that... I have actually tracked the standard committee documents that lead to the addition of `auto` into C++0x and ended up in this one: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf, that states the initial proposal for both `auto` and trailing return types. If you read the introduction you will see this: *For example, the type of the Lambda Library [JP02] expression _1 + _2 + _3 spans several lines, and contains types that are not part of the public interface of the library* [...]

Comment: [...] for which the authors of the proposal suggest uses of `typeof` as a way of resolving the *unknown* type. Because of the burden that it can impose in complex expressions, they propose the addition of a keyword `auto` such that `auto var = expr;` would be similar to `typeof( expr ) var = expr;` but not the same, for some issues that are mentioned later in the document. Feel free to read the document, as it also adds quite some insight into the discussion we have already had for trailing return types.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between Bjarne suggestion to *revisit* `auto` and the actual proposals that lead into the current state of the language. The motivation to actually add `auto` stem not only from Bjarne's point of view but rather from the motivations stated in the different proposals that were discussed. The C++ committee is not *ruled* by Bjarne, and a proposal with only his motivation example might have been rejected (I don't actually think it would, but it *could*). Please don't cry on this :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of useful late return type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T1>
auto inchesToFeet(int inch) -> T1
{
    T1 inches = static_cast<T1>(inch);  
    T1 value = inches/12;
    return value;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    int inches = 29;

    int approxWood = inchesToFeet<int>(inches);
    cout << approxWood << " feet of wood" << endl;

    float exactWire = inchesToFeet<float>(inches);
    cout << exactWire << " feet of wire" << endl;

    return 0;
}

Output:
2 feet of wood
2.41667 feet of wire
```